# How to access a variable outside the block?

Tags: java, android

In this program I have a `TextView` which says "Enter the number of LineData : ".
Below this i have a `EditText` which allows number alone.
Below this I have a `Button` whose function is to display the value from EditText.
To get integer value from `EditText` I used the variable "i" which is inside `Try/Catch` block.
I know that this variable "i" is destroyed outside that block.
But i wanna use that variable to create `TableRow`s in `TableLayout`.
I tried to do this inside the Try block.But I got error.
How can i Fix this??

```
public class Ybus_Activity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ybus);
        final LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        final LinearLayout main = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.android_main_layout);
        TextView getData = new TextView(this);
        getData.setText("Enter the number of LineData : ");
        getData.setId(5);
        getData.setLayoutParams(params);
        main.addView(getData);
        final EditText edText = new EditText(this);
        edText.setId(3);
        edText.setLayoutParams(params);
        edText.setWidth(100);
        edText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
        edText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        edText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance());
        edText.setMaxLines(1);
        main.addView(edText);
        Button bt = new Button(this);
        bt.setText("Click to enter Linedata");
        bt.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        main.addView(bt);
        final TextView text = new TextView(this);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String ed = edText.getText().toString();
                int i = 0;
                try {
                    i = Integer.parseInt(ed);
                    text.setText(i + "");
                } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                    text.setText("Value at TextView is not a valid integer");
                }
            }
        });
        main.addView(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: declare `int i;` before `onCreate`.

Comment: @Raghunandan : Its not working...I need the updated value...But im not receiving it

Comment: it will. it will be initialized on button click. post the updated code

Comment: no bro its not working...I initialized befor onCreate..It is showing that Unfortuanately your app has stopped

Comment: post the updated code an what do you mean by updated value?

Comment: Updated value means If i enter value as 6 for edText the value 6 must be stored in "i".This is actually done in try block...Now i want the same value outside the block

Comment: it will can you post the updated code pls

Comment: i posted...It is down

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare the variable `i` as a instance variable

```
int i;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

Your code inside button click is executed everytime you click the button. However the code outside button click is executed only once.

Hence you were not seeing the updated value

Edit:

```
try {
                i = Integer.parseInt(ed);
                // setting value here
                text.setText(String.valueOf(i));
                // or you can do like this
                // text.setText(String.valueOf(i));
                updatedvalueOfi(i);
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                text.setText("Value at TextView is not a valid integer");
            }
```

Then

```
public void updatedvalueOfi(int value)
{
    Log.i("..........",""+i);
}
```

Edit:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     int i;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        final LinearLayout main = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);
        TextView getData = new TextView(this);
        getData.setText("Enter the number of LineData : ");
        getData.setId(5);
        getData.setLayoutParams(params);
        main.addView(getData);
        final EditText edText = new EditText(this);
        edText.setId(3);
        edText.setLayoutParams(params);
        edText.setWidth(100);
        edText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
        edText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        edText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance());
        edText.setMaxLines(1);
        main.addView(edText);
        Button bt = new Button(this);
        bt.setText("Click to enter Linedata");
        bt.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        main.addView(bt);
        final TextView text = new TextView(this);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String ed = edText.getText().toString();

                try {
                    i = Integer.parseInt(ed);
                    // setting value here
                    text.setText(String.valueOf(i));
                    // or you can do like this
                    // text.setText(String.valueOf(i));

                } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                    text.setText("Value at TextView is not a valid integer");
                }
            }
        });
        main.addView(text);
        final TextView text2 = new TextView(this);
        Button two = new Button(this);
        two.setText("Second");
        main.addView(two);
        main.addView(text2);
        two.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                text2.setText(String.valueOf(i));

            }

        });

    }

}
```

Snap

[image]

Comment: @gkn06 check the edit it will work. it will work even with another button

Comment: @Raghunandan, Nice example as well as explanation +1.

Answer (score 2):

Declare Variable i as static

```
public class Ybus_Activity extends Activity {
//Here Declare the vaiable
 static int i=0;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
}
}
```

Comment: app stopped unfortunately

Comment: stopped unfortunately there may be mistake in assigning your id.I hope that static int i will work

Comment: Okay you do like this det your editText as TEXT instead of only number .I tried that one it works.Go to your graphical layout right click on editText and change is input type as default

and remove this line or make it as comment line 



edText .setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER)

Answer (score 0):

the answer of your quest. is so easy...
just try to put thie parameter i outside of the onclicke of your button ...
like :

```
public class Ybus_Activity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_ybus);
....
....
...
....
int i = 0;    
bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{ 
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        String ed=edText.getText().toString(); 

        try{
          i =Integer.parseInt(ed);
          text.setText(i+"");
        }catch(NumberFormatException ex){
          text.setText("Value at TextView is not a valid integer");
        }
    }
});
...
...
...
}
```

i hope it helped you :)